# (python) How do I obtain specific entries from a dictionary (using keys) as I do with an array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

With an array `x=['A','B','C']`, I can obtain several elements from it by just stating the index: eg.`print(x[0:2])` yields `['A','B']`.

Now for a similar (**ordered**) dictionary `x={1:'A', 2:'B', 3:'C'}`, how would I obtain 'A' and 'B' in the same way, by referencing the keys 1 and 2? Trying a method similar to the array above gives me an error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Note that the key tied to the entries are important, so it won't help converting the dictionary into a list.

Also, I plan on doing this to a lot of entries (>100), so calling each individual one won't be useful. My real program will involve numbered keys starting from 100 and calling keys 200 to 300, for example.

Comment: If your dict will have numbered keys on your real program, then just use `dict.get(number)` in a loop with range 200 to 300.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to retrieve a value from a dictionary is `dict_name[key]`:

```
print x[1], x[2]
>> 'A', 'B'
```

Note that if the key doesn't exist this will raise a `KeyError`. 
A way around it is to use `get(key, default_value)`:

```
print x[9]
>> KeyError
print x.get(9, None)
>> None
```

You can use a `for` loop in order to check multiple keys:

```
for potential_key in range(10):
    print x[potential_key]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I plan on doing this to a lot of entries (>100), so calling each individual one won't be useful. (sorry for not clarifying this)

Comment: @teachmyselfhowtocode Either way you will have to call each key individually or use a `for` loop. There is nothing resembling slices with dictionaries since dictionaries have no sense of order.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually using `OrderedDict`, which places entries in order of assignment. (for loop works fine as well.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> x = {1:'A', 2:'B', 3:'C'}
>>> itemgetter(1, 2)(x)
('A', 'B')

>>> get_1_2 = itemgetter(1, 2)  # Alternative: Save the result function
>>> get_1_2(x)                  #              call it later
('A', 'B')
```

Comment: @teachmyselfhowtocode, You can combine `operator.itemgetter` with `range`: `itemgetter(*range(20, 100))`

Comment: Is `itemgetter` a pythonic term?

Comment: to clarify, `itemgetter(1, 2)` calls `__init__` and then `(x)` invokes `__call__`?

Comment: @teachmyselfhowtocode, yes itemgetter is pythonic and the most efficient method here.

Answer (score 0):

You can map `get()` to the object that describes which keys you want, such as `range()` (which has syntax and results similar to that of slicing):

```
>>> x={1:'A', 2:'B', 3:'C'}
>>> print(*map(x.get, range(1,3)))
A B
```

Or a generator expression instead of `map()`:

```
>>> x={1:'A', 2:'B', 3:'C'}
>>> print(*(x.get(item) for item in range(1,3)))
A B
```

Answer (score 0):

> `>> list(x.values())[0:2]`

This gives the output: ['A', 'B']

Since you mentioned 'ordered' dictionary, this could be a possible solution but without referencing the keys.